# Calcular días transcurridos entre dos fechas en jquery

Tags: jquery

Obtengo la fecha actual en el formato `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
var d = new Date();
var strDate =d.getDate() + "/" + "0" +(d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
```

Necesito contar los días transcurridos entre dos fechas, comparando la fecha que esta en el mismo formato `"dd/mm/yyyy"` con la fecha actual `"strDate"`

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta (y) suerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener los milisegundos entre las dos fechas y pasarlo a días :
Este es un ejmplo con tu mismo formato de fecha

```js
restaFechas = function(f1,f2)
 {
 var aFecha1 = f1.split('/'); 
 var aFecha2 = f2.split('/'); 
 var fFecha1 = Date.UTC(aFecha1[2],aFecha1[1]-1,aFecha1[0]); 
 var fFecha2 = Date.UTC(aFecha2[2],aFecha2[1]-1,aFecha2[0]); 
 var dif = fFecha2 - fFecha1;
 var dias = Math.floor(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
 return dias;
 }
var f1 = '01/01/2017';
var f2='20/06/2017';
alert('Pasaron '+restaFechas(f1,f2)+' dias');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```